# Cannot reduce the fontSize of label in reactjs using semantic-ui-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

If I have form input which label --> I cannot reduce the size of the label.

In this example fontSize will not be applied:

```
<Form.Input label="Username" style={{fontSize: '10px'}}  />
```

Does someone has an idea about how to solve the issue?

Comment: try `style={{fontSize: '10px !important'}}`

Comment: This doesn't help me. Tnx for rply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to split label and input like this below than you can use inline styling:

```
<Form.Input label='Enter Password' type='password' />
vs

<Form.Field>
  <label style={{fontSize: '10px'}}>Enter Password</label>
  <Input type='password' style={{fontSize: '10px'}} />
</Form.Field>
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this simple way to apply css on any component.

```css
.inputCls {
  font-size: 10px !important;
}
```

```html
<Form.Input label="Username" className="inputCls"  />
```

Comment: I dont have permission to use exteranl css. 
Only Semantic and inline css. 
And when i add inline fontsize that applied only on input filed not on label.

Answer (score 2):

There is a cleaner approach which is also demonstrated in the [official docs](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/#shorthand-field-label-object).

Instead of:

```
<Form.Input label="Username" style={{fontSize: '10px'}}  />
```

Pass an object with style preferences to the label prop as follows:

```
<Form.Input label={{ children: "Username", style:{ fontSize: '10px' } }} />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't create external `CSS` files and rules, you can't override the `Label`'s styling with `Form.Input`.

But that's only the "shorthand" (compound) version for:

```
<Form.Field>
  <label>Enter text</label>
  <Input type='text' />
</Form.Field>
```

And with this approach you can override the `Label` styling:

```
<Form.Field>
  <label style={{fontSize: '15px'}}>Enter text</label>
  <Input type='text' />
</Form.Field>
```

See the [docs](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/#shorthand-subcomponent-control)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to customize semantic-ui input font size without the need to create a custom class or use !important.

1. Create a css file (let's call it `input.css`) and add the following rule:

```
.ui.input > input {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

2. Import the css file into your root component.

```
import './input.css'
```

Boom! Input font size adjusted.